# string vs unicode encoding - Struct() argument

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding, enthought

I am experiencing a strange problem that returns the same error, regardless of the encoding I use. The code works well, without the encoding part in Python 2.7.8, but it breaks in 2.7.6 which is the version that I use for all my development.

```
import MIDI_PY2 as md
import glob
import ast
import os
dir = '/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/'
os.chdir(dir)
file_list = []

for file in glob.glob('*.mid'):
    file_list.append((dir + file))

dir = '/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/'
os.chdir(dir)
```

file_list returns this:

```
[u'/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/M1.mid',
 u'/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/M2.mid',
 u'/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/M3.mid',
 u'/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/M4.mid']
```

md.concatenate_midis(file_list,'/Users/luissanchez/Desktop/temp/out.mid') returns this error:

```
-
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-2d7eef92f566> in <module>()
----> 1 md.concatenate_midis(file_list_1,'/Users/user/Desktop/temp/out.mid')

/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/MIDI_PY2.pyc in concatenate_midis(paths, outPath)

/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/MIDI_PY2.pyc in midi2score(midi)

/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/MIDI_PY2.pyc in midi2opus(midi)

TypeError: Struct() argument 1 must be string, not unicode
```

then I modify the code so the first argument is string, not unicode:

```
file_list_1 = [str(x) for x in file_list]
```

which returns:

```
['/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/M1.mid',
 '/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/M2.mid',
 '/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/M3.mid',
 '/Users/user/Desktop/sample midis/M4.mid']
```

running the function concatenate_midis with this last list (file_list_1) returns exactly the same error: TypeError: Struct() argument 1 must be string, not unicode.

Does anybody knows what's going on here? concatenate_midi works well in python 2.7.8, but can't figure out why it doesn't work in what I use, Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 | 64-bit

Thanks

Comment: struct.pack was fixed to accept unicode format strings in Python 2.7.7.

See: https://hg.python.org/cpython/raw-file/f89216059edf/Misc/NEWS

At the top of your question you say you use 2.7.7 in development, but at the bottom you say 2.7.6.  I suspect you're actually using 2.7.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

> error: TypeError: Struct() argument 1 must be string, not unicode.

is usually caused by the [struct.unpack()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) function which in older versions of python requires string arguments and not unicode. Check that struct.unpack() arguments are strings and not unicodes.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause is [`from __future__ ..` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html).

```
>>> type('a')
<type 'str'>
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> type('a')
<type 'unicode'>
```

Check whether your code contains the statement.